# Resolving errors on application start for Logger backend and one of its dependencies not being initialized?

Tags: elixir

I’m using this `Logger` backend in my application:

- [marcelog/logger_logstash_backend: Logstash backend for the Elixir Logger](https://github.com/marcelog/logger_logstash_backend)

In the application’s `mix.exs` file, in the `application` function, `:logger_logstash_backend` is included in the `:applications` key (after `:timex`, on which it relies).

When I start my app via `iex -S mix`, I see LOTS of errors like the following:

```
15:49:48.306 registered_name=Logger function=report_error/5 module=gen_event line=747 file=gen_event.erl pid=<0.2656.0> [error] :gen_event handler {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log} installed in Logger terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:tzdata_current_release, :release_version)
    lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:74: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.current_release_from_table/0
    lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:17: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.simple_lookup/1
    lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:9: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.zone_and_link_list/0
    lib/tzdata.ex:61: Tzdata.zone_exists?/1
    lib/timezone/timezone.ex:358: Timex.Timezone.resolve/3
    lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex:73: LoggerLogstashBackend.log_event/5
    lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex:40: LoggerLogstashBackend.handle_event/2
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:577: :gen_event.server_update/4
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:559: :gen_event.server_notify/4
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:561: :gen_event.server_notify/4
    (stdlib) gen_event.erl:300: :gen_event.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:info, #PID<0.63.0>, {Logger, ["Application ", "logger", " started at " | ":nonode@nohost"], {{2020, 1, 6}, {15, 49, 48, 224}}, [function: "info_started/2", module: :application_controller, line: 1926, file: "application_controller.erl", pid: #PID<0.43.0>]}}
State: %{ex_jsx_opts: [:uescape], host: '127.0.0.1', level: :info, metadata: [], name: :logstash_log, port: 4201, socket: #Port<0.2458>, type: "elixir"}

15:49:48.307 function=error_info/7 module=gen_server line=888 file=gen_server.erl pid=<0.2659.0> [error] GenServer #PID<0.2659.0> terminating
** (stop) {:EXIT, {:badarg, [{:ets, :lookup, [:tzdata_current_release, :release_version], []}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :current_release_from_table, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 74]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :simple_lookup, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 17]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :zone_and_link_list, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 9]}, {Tzdata, :zone_exists?, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata.ex', line: 61]}, {Timex.Timezone, :resolve, 3, [file: 'lib/timezone/timezone.ex', line: 358]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :log_event, 5, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 73]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :handle_event, 2, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 40]}, {:gen_event, :server_update, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 577]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 559]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 561]}, {:gen_event, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 300]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}
Last message: {:gen_event_EXIT, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}, {:EXIT, {:badarg, [{:ets, :lookup, [:tzdata_current_release, :release_version], []}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :current_release_from_table, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 74]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :simple_lookup, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 17]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :zone_and_link_list, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 9]}, {Tzdata, :zone_exists?, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata.ex', line: 61]}, {Timex.Timezone, :resolve, 3, [file: 'lib/timezone/timezone.ex', line: 358]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :log_event, 5, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 73]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :handle_event, 2, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 40]}, {:gen_event, :server_update, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 577]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 559]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 561]}, {:gen_event, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 300]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}}
State: {Logger, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}}

15:49:48.315 initial_call=Logger.Watcher.init/1 function=crash_report/4 module=proc_lib line=508 file=proc_lib.erl pid=<0.2659.0> [error] Process #PID<0.2659.0> terminating
** (exit) {:EXIT, {:badarg, [{:ets, :lookup, [:tzdata_current_release, :release_version], []}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :current_release_from_table, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 74]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :simple_lookup, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 17]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :zone_and_link_list, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 9]}, {Tzdata, :zone_exists?, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata.ex', line: 61]}, {Timex.Timezone, :resolve, 3, [file: 'lib/timezone/timezone.ex', line: 358]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :log_event, 5, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 73]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :handle_event, 2, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 40]}, {:gen_event, :server_update, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 577]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 559]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 561]}, {:gen_event, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 300]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:751: :gen_server.handle_common_reply/8
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Initial Call: Logger.Watcher.init/1
Ancestors: [Logger.BackendSupervisor, Logger.Supervisor, #PID<0.2654.0>]
Message Queue Length: 0
Messages: []
Links: [#PID<0.2658.0>, #PID<0.2656.0>]
Dictionary: []
Trapping Exits: true
Status: :running
Heap Size: 4185
Stack Size: 27
Reductions: 57169

15:49:48.316 function=do_restart/3 module=supervisor line=713 file=supervisor.erl pid=<0.2658.0> [error] Child {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log} of Supervisor Logger.BackendSupervisor terminated
** (exit) {:EXIT, {:badarg, [{:ets, :lookup, [:tzdata_current_release, :release_version], []}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :current_release_from_table, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 74]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :simple_lookup, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 17]}, {Tzdata.ReleaseReader, :zone_and_link_list, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex', line: 9]}, {Tzdata, :zone_exists?, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata.ex', line: 61]}, {Timex.Timezone, :resolve, 3, [file: 'lib/timezone/timezone.ex', line: 358]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :log_event, 5, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 73]}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :handle_event, 2, [file: 'lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex', line: 40]}, {:gen_event, :server_update, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 577]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 559]}, {:gen_event, :server_notify, 4, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 561]}, {:gen_event, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_event.erl', line: 300]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}
Pid: #PID<0.2659.0>
Start Call: Logger.Watcher.start_link({Logger, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}})
Restart: :transient
Shutdown: 5000
Type: :worker

15:49:48.316 function=report_progress/2 module=supervisor line=1419 file=supervisor.erl pid=<0.2658.0> [info]  Child {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log} of Supervisor Logger.BackendSupervisor started
Pid: #PID<0.2678.0>
Start Call: Logger.Watcher.start_link({Logger, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}, {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}})
Restart: :transient
Shutdown: 5000
Type: :worker
```

(The last event isn’t an error.)

The errors seem to be due to the backend relying on `tzdata` having been started and its ETS table existing.

I’ve been ignoring the errors until today. Today, for the first time, my entire application failed to start because there was finally enough of the above errors within a short enough period of time that the supervision tree itself crashed.

I tried moving the application for the backend from the `:applications` key to a `start_phase` function but that didn’t seem to help at all. I’m guessing it’s because the application for the backend is being started by `Logger` itself.

How *can* these errors be resolved or prevented? What *should* (ideally) be changed in either my application or the backend to avoid this or similar issues?

Is the problem that the backend relies on `Timex` and `tzdata` at all? Or is there some way the backend can be started by `Logger` and itself wait until `tzdata` (or `Timex`) has finished loading before it begins handling log events normally?

The GitHub project for the backend doesn’t seem to have been actively maintained for some time. I’m actually using a personal fork of the code currently. So I’m open to suggestions to change the backend code.

---

I previously posted a topic on [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/) about this:

- [Resolving errors for Logger backend on application start? - Questions / Help - Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/resolving-errors-for-logger-backend-on-application-start/28069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve/prevent all of these errors (and some new ones that appeared after the first set were resolved).

I removed the backend from the `:applications` key – that was good to do anyways. I'm going to try to cleanup the dependencies more generally later, e.g. remove the `:applications` key entirely and add only the necessary 'extra' apps to the `:extra_applications` key. (My app is older than those changes in Elixir; hence the stale state of this code/configuration.)

I modified my `Logger` configuration to NOT include this backend. Instead, I added a 'start phase' for the application; in `mix.exs`:

```
       # Start `logger_logstash_backend` after `timex` (and `tzdata`) have been started:
       start_phases: [{:logger_logstash_backend, []}]
```

and in my main app module:

```
  def start_phase(:logger_logstash_backend, _start_type, _phase_args) do
    IO.puts "Starting application start phase `:logger_logstash_backend`"

    case Application.fetch_env(:my_app, :logger_logstash_backend) do
      :error ->
        IO.puts "No configuration value was found for the Logger Logstash backend."

      {:ok, options} ->
        backend = {LoggerLogstashBackend, :logstash_log}

        # From the docs for `Logger.add_backend`:
        #
        # > Backends added by this function are not persisted. Therefore
        # > if the Logger application or supervision tree is restarted,
        # > the backend won't be available. If you need this guarantee,
        # > then configure the backend via the application environment.
        #
        # This shouldn't be an issue for us as the `Logger` application and supervision tree don't seem
        # to have ever needed to be restarted; just started normally when the app is started, i.e. when
        # running the app locally in a `:dev` environment or when starting a new instance in production.

        Logger.add_backend(backend)
        Logger.configure_backend(backend, options)
    end

    :ok
  end
```

This *feels* like the 'right way' to fix problems like this, e.g. with an application or other 'server' process that needs to be started during application startup, but *after* some other application or server process on which it depends.

Answer (score 0):

While error message might look a bit confusing, you should not include `:logger_logstash_backend` into `applications`. The whole source code of `LoggerLogstashBackend` is an [implementation of `:gen_event`](https://github.com/marcelog/logger_logstash_backend/blob/master/lib/logger_logstash_backend.ex), as nearly all [the logger backends](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-backends). It does not implement [`Application`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Application.html?) behaviour nor is intended to be used as an application.

Your `applications` should look like `[:logger, :timex]`, as clearly stated in [`README`](https://github.com/marcelog/logger_logstash_backend#using-it-with-mix).

I am unsure why it does not complain about an attempt to start inexisting application, probably because the default implementation of `:gen_event` apparently has `start_link/2` (<del>or `use Timex` injects it</del> [it does not](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/3.6.1/lib/timex.ex#L18-L27).)

---

*UPD* Either change `:applications` to `:extra_applications`, or explicitly start `:tzdata` application. `Timer` relies on it, and `:applications` discards all the automatically started chains of applications in favor of what is explicitly stated there.

`Timex` fails to start because it relies on `:tzdata` application, which is not started.

Comment: You seem to be correct in that the backend is not an application and thus shouldn't be included in the `:applications` key value. But that point seems to be entirely unrelated to the errors. I just tried running my app after removing the backend from `:applications` and I still see the same errors (and my app failed to start again).

Comment: What probably means that Timex app fails to start.

Comment: Either change `:applications` to `:extra_applications`, or explicitly start `:tzdata` application. `Timer` relies on it, and `:applications` discards all the automatically started chains of applications in favor of what is explicitly stated there.

Comment: Both Timex, and `tzdata`, DO start. If the app does NOT fail to start, it runs fine. And it only fails to start infrequently and it appears that that only happens if enough errors are raised within a short enough period to cause the relevant supervisor to fail after restarting `Logger` too many times. Adding `:tzdata` to `:applications` didn't obviously affect the errors at all.

Comment: I think that, outside of removing the `Timex` dependency from the backend, I'd need to dynamically add the backend to Logger in an application `start_phase` function, i.e. after both `Timex` and `tzdata` have started. I might also need to explicitly wait until the `tzdata` ETS table(s) are initialized and accessible before dynamically adding the backend.